# Google Maps: Query from the blog post

Tags: google-maps

I went through this excellent tutorial of google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch but i din't understand the part where the xml file generated is read by the API. i went through the post twice but still not getting it. Could someone explain it to me please.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out which part you didn't understand so I'll give a broad overview.

Reading the XML happens here:

```
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
  var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
  var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
  GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = GXml.parse(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
```

`searchUrl` points to the php file with appropriate parameters, then `GDownloadUrl` performs the Ajax call to the php file. `function(data)` is the callback that is run when the XML is returned. Finally, `markers` is produced from the XML, taking elements with tag name `marker`. Then the rest of that block of code is placing markers and updating the sidebar with the results.

Comment: Does this file phpsqlsearch_genxml.php gets saved somewhere? I tried integrating with the zend framework but i get the following error: 
"error on line 123 at column 13: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

Comment: I don't work with PHP but looking at the tutorial I guess the code section labeled phpsqlsearch_genxml.php should be copied and pasted into a file in the same folder as the javascript. I don't see Zend mentioned so I would leave that out.